# 10-dimensional and 15-dimensional matrix representations of $SU(5)$: explicit 24 Lie algebra generators

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, grand-unification

There are some previous discussions in this post [Representation of the $\rm SU(5)$ model in GUT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509363/)  which confused me. So I want to follow up with a new question.

It is easy to write down the 5-dimensional matrix representations of $SU(5)$ with 24 Lie algebra rank-5 matrix generators as:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### My question

is that based on the fact of
$$
5 \times 5 = 10_A + 15_S
$$

How do we write down the 10-dimensional and 15-dimensional matrix representations of $SU(5)$?

- 10-dimensional matrix representations of $SU(5)$ with 24 Lie algebra rank-10 matrix generators.
- 15-dimensional matrix representations of $SU(5)$ with 24 Lie algebra rank-15 matrix generators.

**Warning:** Note that the $10_A$ is not just the rank-5 antisymmetric matrix as Lie algebra generators because that only gives 10 such matrices which generate the $SO(5)$ instead of $SU(5)$.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214397/11127

Comment: Yes thanks- I thought math and physics people could provide different types of thinkings - which indeed people do. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Let's for simplicity sketch how the construction goes for the Lie group $U(5)$ and leave it for the reader to modify it to $SU(5)$.
2. OP is interested in realizing the group representations
   $${\bf 10}~:=~{\bf 5}\wedge{\bf 5}~=~\begin{array}{r} [~~]\cr [~~] \end{array} \qquad\text{and}\qquad {\bf 15}~:=~{\bf 5}\odot {\bf 5}~=~[~~]~[~~],\tag{1}$$
   where ${\bf 5}=[~~]$ denotes the defining/fundamental representation of $U(5)$.
   (NB: In this answer we often [identify a representation with its vector space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/2451).)
3. Together they form a 25-dimensional reducible tensor representation
   $$ {\bf 25}~:=~{\bf 5}\otimes{\bf 5}~=~{\bf 5}\wedge{\bf 5}~\oplus~{\bf 5}\odot{\bf 5}. \tag{2}$$
   Here $\otimes$ denotes the standard (un-symmetrized) [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).
4. Explicitly, the tensor representation
   $$ R:~ U(5)~\to~ {\rm End}({\bf 5}\otimes{\bf 5}),\tag{3}$$
   is given as
   $$  R(g)(\sum_iv^i_L\otimes v^i_R)~=~\sum_igv^i_L\otimes gv^i_R ,\tag{4}$$
   where
   $$g\in~ U(5), \qquad v^i_L,v^i_R~\in~{\bf 5}.\tag{5} $$
5. The corresponding Lie algebra representation
   $$ r:~ u(5)~\to~ {\rm End}({\bf 5}\otimes{\bf 5}),\tag{6}$$
   is given as
   $$  r(x)(\sum_iv^i_L\otimes v^i_R)~=~\sum_ixv^i_L\otimes v^i_R + \sum_iv^i_L\otimes xv^i_R,\tag{7}$$
   where
   $$x\in~ u(5), \qquad v^i_L,v^i_R~\in~{\bf 5}.\tag{8} $$
   By choosing a basis for ${\bf 5}$, it is then in principle possible to calculate a $25\times 25$ matrix representation of the basis elements for the Lie algebra $u(5)$.
6. The tensor representations (3) and (6) respect the splitting (2) into OP's sought-for representations (1). This is in principle the answer to OP's question.
7. On the other hand, OP considers the 25-dimensional Lie algebra $$u(5)=u(5)_A\oplus u(5)_S \tag{9}$$ of anti-Hermitian $5\times 5$ matrices, which  separates into a 10-dimensional subspace $u(5)_A$ of real antisymmetric matrices, and a 15-dimensional subspace $u(5)_S$ of imaginary symmetric matrices.
8. The [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation)
   $${\rm Ad}: ~U(5)~\to~ {\rm End}(u(5)),\tag{10}$$
   is given by
   $$\begin{align} {\rm Ad}(g)x~:=~&gxg^{-1}, \cr g~\in~&U(5), \qquad x~\in~u(5),\end{align}\tag{11}$$
   acts on the Lie algebra $u(5)$, but it does *not* respect the splitting (9).

Comment: thanks so much for this +1!

Comment: But sorry in which equations do you obtain the 10-dimensional matrix representations of (5) and the 15-dimensional matrix representations of (5) ?

Comment: This part is nice "(5)=(5)⊕(5)(9) of anti-Hermitian 5×5 matrices, which separates into a 10-dimensional subspace (5) of real antisymmetric matrices, and a 15-dimensional subspace (5) of imaginary symmetric matrices." but we hope to make these rank-10 and rank-15 matrices explicitly

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer --- could you clarify: " adjoint representation acts on the Lie algebra (5), but it does not respect the splitting $(5)=(5)_⊕(5)_$." What do we learn from the properties here? (I admire you including the discussions, points by points, so I could easily follow.)

Comment: First of all, do you agree that the content of the quoted sentence is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, despite my near-promise in the question you quote, I don't know of a source that computes these *bulky* sets of 24 10×10 and 15×15 extraordinarily *sparse* matrices. The best I could do is illustrate for you the compact answer of @Qmechanic 's (2) and make sure you visualize it the way I do (and everyone should, arguably).

I will use your  $\lambda_1$ as an example of the 5×15 generator in your non-standard normalization, $A_1$ for the corresponding 10×10 one, and $S_1$ for the 15×15 one. But, alas!, I won't even get to computing those, but just the reducible 25×25 coproduct one, $A_1\oplus S_1$,
$$
\Delta (\lambda_1)_{25}= \lambda_1\otimes 1\!\!1 _5 +   1\!\!1 _5 \otimes   \lambda_1= A_1\oplus S_1 . 
$$

My convention for tensor products is "right-into-left", that is, the right tensor factor vectors/matrices multiplies the left vector/matrix numerical entries.

The above coproduct then is a straightforward ***block matrix***, where I write the 5×5 blocks compactly, symbolically,
$$
\Delta (\lambda_1)_{25}= \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &   1\!\!1 _5  &0&0&0 \\
 1\!\!1 _5 & \lambda_1 &0&0&0\\
0&0&\lambda_1 &0&0 \\
0&0&0&\lambda_1&0  \\
0&0&0&0&\lambda_1  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

As illustrated in both answers to the ${\mathfrak su} (2)$ example of your [choice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632973/what-does-the-notation-frac12-otimes-frac12-1-oplus-0-mean-exact), an orthogonal similarity Clebsch transformation  effects a basis change  from this uncoupled to the ***coupled*** basis,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A_1&0\\0&S_1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and likewise for *all* 23 remaining generator 25×25 matrices like this one. I would not dream of producing this Clebsch matrix, since, as I said in my answer you cite, it's a project.

How does this coproduct matrix act on a simple (too simple!) sample vector? Let's write the column vectors as transposes of row vectors to save space:
$$
v\equiv [1,0,0,0,0]^T , \qquad w\equiv [0,1,0,0,0]^T,\\
v\otimes w= [0,1,0,0,...,0]^T_{25} ~.
$$
It is evident that $\lambda_1$ acts as a straight "spin flip-flop" on the two vectors, $v\leftrightarrow w$, and
$$
\Delta(\lambda_1)~~ v\otimes w = v\otimes v +   w\otimes w = 
\Delta(\lambda_1) ~~w\otimes v \\
=[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,...,0  ]^T_{25}~ .
$$

Now, observe $ v\otimes w + w\otimes v$ transforms just as above under $\Delta(\lambda_1) $, and is in the **15**; whereas the $ v\otimes w - w\otimes v$ in the **10** is in the kernel of $\Delta(\lambda_1)$; that's what makes the example too simple. In the coupled basis, it would be in the kernel of $A_1$.

$A_1$ is, of course, not trivial for *su*(5). Had we taken the messier  $u\equiv [0,0,1,0,0]^T$ instead of *w*, we would have documented nontrivial action.

These visualization finger exercises might, or might not, be of use in your project.

Comment: many thanks - I really appreciate it - let me digest in details.